# Require the user to enable macros

Tags: excel, vba

I made a "Welcome" sheet, which says macros should be enabled

If the macros are enabled, the Welcome sheet is hidden,
If macros are disabled, all sheets are hidden except the "Welcome"

This is the code I have, it runs when opening the file, but at closing it declares an error

I have installed the module in `ThisWorkbook`

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim Current As Worksheet
    For Each Current In Worksheets
         Current.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Next Current
    Worksheets("welcome").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    End Sub


'=========   
    Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
        Dim Current As Worksheet
        For Each Current In Worksheets
            If Current.Name <> "welcome" Then
                Current.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
            End If
        Next Current
    End Sub
```

Can anyone help me identify the error?

[image]

Comment: Make sure to first make the welcome sheet visible, you cannot have all sheets hidden in a workbook.

Comment: Right! I forgot about this rule